# Extract the "Manager" field from Project Information using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

Just wondering if its possible to access the "Manager" field within MS Project > Info > Project Information > Summary tab field?

I'm able to extract the Task object (Project) defined within this document [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/project.task][1], just can't see a way to access not only Manager but Company, Category, Keywords etc.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look under builtinproperties.

Something like...

```
Debug.Print ThisProject.BuiltinDocumentProperties("Author")
```